# Unable to add plugins or platform to ionic3 project

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins

As soon as I run command *cordova add platform* or *ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git* I get the error stated below.

```
**(node:5072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): CordovaError: Cordova does not know add; try `cordova help` for a l
ist of all the available commands.
(node:5072) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**
```

I tried degrading cordova but it did not work. How do I solve this problem?

EDIT : *cordova platform add android* gave me error:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0
(node:3444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~7.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
(node:3444) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line you entered is wrong. The command line is

`$ ionic cordova platform add android`

or

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

Comment: i tried the command line u suggested and it gave me another error. I have showen it above in EDIT section.

Comment: Install cordova 7 with  $ sudo npm install -g cordova@7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $ cordova platform add android
```